# Correct method to call .each on dynamically created elements?

Tags: jquery, events

Following on from the Answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/1207393/1786228 and the now quite old jQuery plugin (http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-create-event/)

What is the correct event for `on` to catch when new elements are created? For instance, I have input boxes in which I setup typeahead/autocomplete. I do that with:

```
$(.input_box).each( function() { 
  // set stuff here 
  // setup options etc
  // apply autocomplete plugin to element (this is a jQuery plugin)
  var ac = $(this).autocomplete(acOptions);
});
```

I then have a button to add more of the same input boxes to the form. How can I call that `.each` function just for the new input box? If I use `$(.input_box).each...` again, the original boxes have the plugin added a second time.

I basically want to do the below but there's no "create" event to bind to.

```
$(document).on("create", "input_box", function(e) { 
  // set stuff here 
  // setup options etc
  // apply autocomplete plugin to element (this is a jQuery plugin)
  var ac = $(this).autocomplete(acOptions);
} );
```

Is there such an event? If not, what is the best method to achieve this?

Comment: Personally I would not go for the livequery plugin in your case.You might come across DOMNodeInserted proposed in the DOM Level 2 spec but since this has been deprecated in the DOM Level 3 spec you should not rely on using this as well. Would it be possible for you to provide a working fiddle of your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned above: you could using mutation events. But these events have some limitations: No support for IE prior to version 9, and there are some performance issues with these events too. In your case you would to listen to **DOMNodeInserted**. A possible example:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function(event){
    var target = event.srcElement || event.target;
    if (target && target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'input') {
        // do what you want to do here....
    }
});
```

What I would prefer in your case is a bit simpler: Put your init logic in a seperate function and call this function each time after manipulating the DOM. Inside this function add a class or data value to each element which is initialized and check for this class to be sure you initialize only once:

```
function init() {
    $('.input_box').not('.initialized').each( function() { 
        var ac = $(this).addClass('initialized').autocomplete(acOptions);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks - that does the job nicely. The other option I thought of immediately after posting was to check if the plugin attribute (ac which I attach to a data attribute) was present. I prefer this however as the code is much cleaner.

Comment: One additional point for other readers: if you are cloning elements to which you apply the above method, the new elements will include the 'initialized' class. So, after you clone them, be sure to .removeClass('initialized') them before calling init().